# JS code with table header fixed TH width must be equal to TD width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Header fixed on scroll works fine. But what I want,

**Header TH should be equal to Body TD.**

[image]

you can see both have different widths right now.
If the question is unclear please let me know. I don't want to use any other JS LIB or plugin.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.headerFixed = function (topOffSetVal,fTableID,topPosition) {
    var tableWidth = $('#'+fTableID).width();    
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > topOffSetVal){
                $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').css({'position':'fixed','top':topPosition+'px','margin-left':'0px','width':tableWidth+'px'});
            }else{
                $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').removeAttr('style')
            }
        });
        $( window ).resize(function() {
                  tableWidth = $('#'+fTableID).width();    
              $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').css({'position':'fixed','top':topPosition+'px','margin-left':'0px','width':tableWidth+'px'});
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myID').headerFixed(400,'myID',0);
});
```

```css
.table tr, .table td{
 border:0.1px solid #ddd;
}
.table thead{
 background:#C00; color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="1235" border="0" align="center" class="table" id="myID" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="45">Sr#</th>
                <th align="center">MAP</th>
                <th width="112">YARD ID</th>
                <th width="85">NAME</th>
                <th width="107">REGION</th>
                <th width="150">YARD PORT</th>
                <th width="124">ADDRESS</th>
                <th width="168">ACCESS INFO</th>
                <th width="130">CAPACITY</th>
                <th width="104">TIMING</th>
                <th width="125">Web</th>
                <th align="center" width="128">Auction</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td align="center">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x84?text=Image Not Found :(" />
                </td>
                <td>3453</td>
                <td>test name</td>
                <td>kanagawa</td>
                <td>Ktoyo</td>
                <td>Test address here, address address address address</td>
                <td>Access info goes here Access info goes here</td>
                <td>5600</td>
                <td>80:50 PM</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href='javascript:;' title="Delete Record">Delete</a>
                    <a href='' title="Images Edit">Edit Image</a>
                    <a href='' title="Time Edit">Time Edit</a>
                    <a href='' title="Edit Record">Edit Rec.</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Sr#</th>
                <th>MAP</th>
                <th>YARD ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>REGION</th>
                <th>YARD PORT</th>
                <th>ADDRESS</th>
                <th>ACCESS INFO</th>
                <th>CAPACITY</th>
                <th>TIMING</th>
                <th>Show on Web</th>
                <th>Auction</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 </table>
```

Thanks regards Zaid Bin Khalid

Comment: why are you passing 1233?

Comment: position fixed stretched THEAD @karthick that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a fixed width of 1233px that's the reason the header.th  != body.td

Update your jquery function code with this

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.headerFixed = function (topOffSetVal,fTableID,topPosition) {
    var tableWidth = $('#'+fTableID).width();    
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() > topOffSetVal){
                $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').css({'position':'fixed','top':topPosition+'px','margin-left':'0px','width':tableWidth+'px'});
            }else{
                $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').removeAttr('style')
            }
        });
        $( window ).resize(function() {
                  tableWidth = $('#'+fTableID).width();    
              $("#"+fTableID+' > thead').css({'position':'fixed','top':topPosition+'px','margin-left':'0px','width':tableWidth+'px'});
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myID').headerFixed(400,'myID',0);
});
```

Comment: it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/ccrzoL2k/1/. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have updated the code with resize functionality. Make sure you are updating the code properly. Because it works fine in the js fiddle

Comment: What if I have a nested table structure?

Comment: then you have to post your question with that structure. even if it's a nested table structure you will be using the headerFixed function right?. Then you can debug and see what is causing the issue. Most likely you may have to update the margin-left property depending on the table's position. Try to solve it. If not post that as a question

Comment: Thanks, @karthick for your kind help.